# Error Ajax is not a function in bootstrap-table

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-table

Error in bootstrap-table

> Uncaught TypeError: a.ajax is not a function
>       at p.initServer (bootstrap-table.min.js:8)(...)

CODE:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
 $('#table').bootstrapTable({
            url: 'data1.json',
            columns: [{
                field: 'id',
                title: 'Id',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                field: 'name',
                title: 'Name',
                sortable: true
            }]            
          });

        </script>
```

Comment: Did you import jquery library to the page?

Comment: Sorry, I was using jquery slim...

Thank You!

Comment: Did it resolve ur problem? or are you still getting the issue?

Comment: I solved, change library  jquery.slim > jquery